# How to check the "non-prefix"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Here's my `RegisterRoutes` within `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Worktypes",
        url: "Clinic/Worktypes/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Worktypes", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    // default (finance)
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Which works, accessing `/Clinic/Worktypes`. The problem is that it works also if I digit `/Worktypes` in the url. How can I prevent accessing "non-prefix" controllers?

Comment: The default route is making it work without a prefix. Maybe specifying the namespace in the routes would solve your problem?

Comment: @Borka what do you mean? Example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't this this is the most elegant solution, maybe probably there are better ones.

But, I had this similar problem on a project of mine and I resolved by using namespace constraints.

So, in your route registration provided that your prefix controller has a different namespace than the rest of the controllers that need to go to the default route

```
var route = routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    // lets assume that your non prefixed controllers are under the WebApp.Controllers
    // namespace
    namespaces: new []{ "WebApp.Controllers" }
);

// note, this is an important part. Basically you tell this route to match only the 
// controller that are under that namespace, specified in the route
route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: All of my controllers are on the same namespace... so this won't work :(

Comment: Yeah, if i think of something else ill update my answer :)